# ExitInstance not called when exit(1) is used

Tags: windows, mfc

With our MFC app a normal clean exit calls CWinApp::ExitInstance() and then CWinApp::~CWinApp. But if exit(1) is called, only CWinApp::~CWinApp fires, ExitInstance is skipped. I know exit(1) shouldn't be used with MFC, but we have a legacy app that uses it in 100's of places and I'm wary of replacing it with a PostMessage or something totally different.

What is the best solution here?

1. Do some magic windows thing so ExitInstance is actually called
2. Replace exit(1) with something else even though we don't want to
3. Use atexit somehow to call ExitInstance
4. Have our CWinApp dtr call ExitInstance, if it hasn't been called already
5. Try to empty out ExitInstance and just do all cleanup in dtr.  Probably not possible?
6. Other?

Comment: The impetus here is a crash, we shutdown a worker thread in ExitInstance, and since exit(1) skips that part, the thread crashes. The thread (probably unwisely) is repeatedly calling method in a global object which gets deleted on exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the sort of work you're doing in `ExitInstance`.  You have to make sure you understand what it's doing, and how changing the context will affect it.

With that caveat, the most obvious approach is to move the work you're doing in `ExitInstance` to a separate procedure, `MyExitInstance`.  Call `MyExitInstance` from `ExitInstance`.  Replace the calls to `exit` with calls to a procedure that calls `MyExitInstance` and then calls `exit`.

Note that I'm assuming here that's in only your own code in `ExitInstance` that matters, not anything the framework may be doing for you.

Comment: (Of course, the *proper* solution would be to rewrite the legacy application, but I'm assuming that isn't an option.)

Comment: This sounds reasonable although our option #4 should produce the same runtime behavior? But #4 additionally catches the case that someone is calling exit(1) in a library we can't control. I don't know if that happens anywhere, but it's theoretically possible. But your idea probably gets 99% of the exits, and possibly 100% because I don't know if any library would be so bold.

Comment: Also we are rewriting this application but we're not done yet! And in the mean time we are still doing maintenance releases of the older one, and this is a bug we have to fix. We could just shutdown the threads in dtr instead of ExitInstance, but we're just wary of still bypassing all the other ExitInstance code -- although doing the minimal change does fix the crash.

Comment: Although extracting the contents of ExitInstance so we call a non-framework function instead of calling ExitInstance itself is a really good idea. We could do that with #4 or do it by replacing exit(1) calls it seems, so yes very helpful answer.

Comment: The problem with calling ExitInstance yourself (if I understand correctly) is that it isn't just your code, there's also framework code which is not designed to be used in that way.  I'm not sure that using the dtr would work properly anyway with regards to the problem thread, because surely it isn't legal to call a method on an object whose destructor is running.